# Is there a way to flatten this SQL data set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have the following results in a temp-table:

```
CountyName  BatchNumber TotalResult
countyA     6294        69
countyA     6295        298
countyB     6295        12
countyC     6294        36
countyC     6295        32
```

This table will always contain 2 (and only 2) values in the "BatchNumber" column.  I'd like to grab a list of results in the following format:

```
CountyName  Batch1  Batch2
countyA     69      298
countyB     null    12
countyC     36      32
```

Is this possible in SQL?  I know it would be easy to grab a flattened list of min and max "TotalResult" values, but what I want is "TotalResult" values based on min and max "BatchNumber".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select min(BatchNumber) as Batch1, max(BatchNumber) as Batch2
    from T
)
select
    CountyName,
    sum(case when BatchNumber = Batch1 then TotalResult end) as Batch1,
    sum(case when BatchNumber = Batch2 then TotalResult end) as Batch2
from T cross apply data
group by CountyName;
```

The `sum` operation is kind of a dummy operation. With just a single matching row in each group you could just as easily use `min` or `max`. But summing would let you handle multiples should that become necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply conditional aggregation, however, using `DENSE_RANK` rather than the value of a column:

```sql
--Sample data
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('countyA',6294,69),
                ('countyA',6295,298),
                ('countyB',6295,12),
                ('countyC',6294,36),
                ('countyC',6295,32))V(CountyName,BatchNumber,TotalResult)),
--Solution
DR AS(
    SELECT CountyName,
           BatchNumber,
           TotalResult,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BatchNumber ASC) AS DR
    FROM VTE)
SELECT CountyName,
       MAX(CASE DR.DR WHEN 1 THEN TotalResult END) AS Batch1,
       MAX(CASE DR.DR WHEN 2 THEN TotalResult END) AS Batch2
FROM DR
GROUP BY CountyName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` with pivoting logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CountyName ORDER BY BatchNumber) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    CountyName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN TotalResult END) AS Batch1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN TotalResult END) AS Batch2
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    CountyName
ORDER BY
    CountyName;
```

Note that this doesn't generate the *exact* output you expect.  However, for `countyB`, which has only one batch number, it seems arbitrary as to where we report the single value.

Comment: Looks like it's based on `DENSE_RANK` of the value of `BatchNumber`, rather than the `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I didn't see the PIVOT option

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select CountyName
              ,Value = TotalResult
              ,Item =  concat('Batch',row_number() over (partition by CountyName order by BatchNumber) )
        From YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Item in ([Batch1],[Batch2]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
CountyName  Batch1  Batch2
countyA     69      298
countyB     12      NULL
countyC     36      32
```